# How to handle this situation?

Tags: discussion, support, voting-fraud, sock-puppets

I had a little issue with an user insulting me in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36424659/1324033):

> @jordi-castilla : **hey dumb** :) read question and answers properly before poking your nose unnecessarily in someone else's business :) File you mentioned exists only while creating a file and person who has asked the questiuon does not have any issue while creating a file :) he has issue while checking if file exists :) and in checking file exists he is not checking getFilesDir(). **I pray God to give an IQ atleast of room temperature** :) may god bless u :)

But ok I flagged comments and tried to be polite:

> **1)** please learn some education and how to be polite. (you're flagged btw) **2)** please check createFile method in FileUtility and explain to me what new are you giving to OP and why you ignore the utility class specially created by OP `file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "//" + fileName);` **3)** god has nothing to do here and either in my life, thanks.

and help OP...

> @Joe, you already have an utility class doing this job and passing context correctly.... simply add extra info to question in order we can reproduce your mistake...

Finally OP found a solution:

> Thanks for the help guys, "root" was null and after setting root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); the code works perfect now.

But commented this:

> **I will upvote ye all now. I have another account with my gmail I think that I haven't touched in a couple years. – Joe 52 secs ago**

A minute later, all answers (and the question) were upvoted, as announced.

- Is it legal to upvote yourself with another own account?
- Should I flag the comment? User? Question?

---

<strike>#UPDATE:</strike>

- <strike>I've flagged question asking for a mod (still no action) **BUT**</strike>
- <strike>**OP's user has been deleted few minutes ago... WTF???**</strike>

*My apologizes and thanks to Brad and BoltClock, I didn't know deleting user was a mod action. My thought was: user jon was specially created by a more rep user to ask a silly question, after, more rep user upvotes all actions in question and deletes user jon when question was answered... my apologizes, and thanks. :)*

Comment: You cannot flag users. Flag the post, not the comment, as the mods will need the former to gather proof of voting abuse. Then disengage and move on.

Comment: LOL, sorry, but...

Comment: Moar LOL: 'Thanks for the help guys, "root" was null',  all that for a NPE?  Is debugging actually illegal now, or just socially unacceptable?

Comment: hehehhe... @MartinJames not sure, but might be dangerous somewhere :P actually I only readed question, downvoted, commented to a wrong answer and moved on, but insults make me return, not to answer question  but to follow it's evolution....

Comment: Are there undergound 'gdbEasy' bars, where people can go and debug a program without being busted by the cops?   It's about time debug prohibition was repealed.

Comment: Imma changing my name to Eliot Ness.  Imma gonna be untouchable:)

Comment: @Martin James: Debugging your *own* code has been socially unacceptable for the longest time. It's why Stack Overflow exists.

Comment: Regarding the "still no action" part of your update, what more did you want us to do? Your flag was marked as helpful at the time the multiple sock puppet accounts of this user were removed 42 minutes ago, and all offending comments were deleted. Is there something more that we should have done here?

Comment: @BoltClock lol ......................

Comment: @Brad Larson: "what more did you want us to do?" *Not* delete their puppets, judging by their reaction to the deletion of the asker...

Comment: @BradLarson you left the user physically alive?  Could you not have offed him/her as well as the accounts?

Comment: Orite - aparrently, murdering users is illegal:(

Comment: Oh well, my accounts have gone:(  './createSOaccounts +c100 >nextbatch.acc

Comment: @BradLarson so sorry I didn't know was mod action. My thought was: user jon was specially created by a more rep user to ask a silly question, after, more rep user upvotes all actions in question and deletes user jon when question was answered... my apologizes, and thanks. :)

Comment: @BoltClock please check my update or comment. ;)

Comment: @JordiCastilla: you can't self-delete your account once you have created content. So joe could not have deleted their own account, because they had asked a question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters really? Actually that makes sense... Didn't know about that! I feel lucky now of being insulted hehehe... thanks a lot

Comment: So which one was your issue? The offensive comment or the "im gonna upvote y'all" comment, both?

Comment: @JustDoIt my questions are at the end of the post... Offensive comments happen with new users too often... They are there just to add context

Comment: To me they're two different issues, although its the same user, I don't see a relation between both situations.

Comment: They are different users, and again, they are there just to add context, insults are not a problem for me, I know how to act...

Comment: @JustDoIt you think is not clear: *Is it legal to upvote yourself with another own account?Should I flag the comment? User? Question?*

Comment: Two different users, *even easier*. Your **real** issue can completely survive without the first for *context* Like I said, there's no real connection between both issues. I would delete the first since its just a bunch of noise. But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Flag the post if someone is admitting to sockpuppeting like that. Make sure you explain the flag properly, so the mods can quickly see what's going on.

Keep in mind that some actions taken by a moderator aren't necessarily visible for "us users". The fact that the OP's account is gone could be related to a mod merging or getting rid of sockpuppets.

---

That said, there are a couple of things I'd have done differently:

Next time, try to avoid being passive-aggressive. *"please learn some education and how to be polite. (you're flagged btw)"* isn't exactly "Polite".

Also, you may want to work on your grammar a bit. Here's how I would've worded that first comment:

> *"First, please don't resort to namecalling on Stack Overflow. Also, please check the `createFile` method in `FileUtility` and explain what new information you're providing, and why you ignore the utility class specially created by OP"*

Ignore irrelevant comments where possible and don't mention that you flagged someone. Both don't add to the discussion.

Lists like you've added don't really work too well in comments, either.

Comment: I'm curious why I'm getting this many downvotes. How is this answer not helpful or incorrect?

Comment: Perhaps you have fans?

Comment: @Gimby: That's possible. Fans can have weird ways of showing affection...